# Game progress far below 100% after beating the game?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

While playing *Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3*, I killed Makrov, the game ended and I watched the credits. Yet my progress bar still shows only 50% of the tasks finished.

How can I get the missing progress? Do I need other endings or tasks to do? I don't have much interest in SpecOps missions. I'd rather continue playing my last save.

Comment: You've finished the game. I think the % complete is probably taking into account collectibles (intelligence?)

Comment: I've updated your question to be easier to understand. However, I'm not 100% sure the second part is really what you have in mind. Edit it yourself again or leave a comment if it's not really accurate.

Comment: the other 50% is the multiplayer i believe. try re installing the game if you have already completed multiplayer. :]

Answer (score 8):

To get 100% of the tasks you have to:

- Finish the campaign on Veteran difficulty
- Find all enemy intel(which can be done at any difficulty level)

Answer (score 0):

How do i get 100% completion on mw3?

Well its simple, you have to complete mw3 on the difficulty mode veteran.
   Once you have done that you need to do another thing, you need to collect
   pieces of enemy intelligence. You can just do all that on veteran but its
   easier to get Intel on recruit mode.

Comment: this doesn't provide any (useful) information to what has already been said